# Search file, move folder/files

Tags: batch-file

I have my games on an HDD. I want to move the game I want to play to a SSD before playing.

I wonder if it’s possible to create a batch script which includes these steps:

- Search for x file in x folder
- If found open it
- If not found move x folder to x folder
- After moving open x file

Okay here is the code I put together. It seems to work. Not sure if this is the easiest/most efficient way.

Go easy on me, this is my first time. :)

```
@echo off
if exist "C:\Games\A Plague Tale Requiem\APlagueTaleRequiem_x64.exe" (
    call "C:\Games\A Plague Tale Requiem\APlagueTaleRequiem_x64.exe"
) else (
    xcopy /e "D:\Games\A Plague Tale Requiem\" "C:\Games\A Plague Tale Requiem\"
    call "C:\Games\A Plague Tale Requiem\APlagueTaleRequiem_x64.exe"
)
```

Comment: If your code works and you just want comments on it, you should post it on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead of here. That said, the only thing I see that I would change is that you don't need `call` to run executables.

Comment: I would go further, I would restructure it, _(and change the deprecated `xcopy.exe`, for the utility which replaced it fifteen years ago, `Robocopy.exe`)_. Example: **1.** ```@If Not Exist "C:\Games\A Plague Tale Requiem\APlagueTaleRequiem_x64.exe" If Exist "D:\Games\A Plague Tale Requiem\APlagueTaleRequiem_x64.exe" %SystemRoot%\System32\Robocopy.exe "D:\Games\A Plague Tale Requiem" "C:\Games\A Plague Tale Requiem" /E 1>NUL 2>&1```, **2**. ```If Exist "C:\Games\A Plague Tale Requiem\APlagueTaleRequiem_x64.exe" Start "" "C:\Games\A Plague Tale Requiem\APlagueTaleRequiem_x64.exe"```.